# Any way to get raw voltage value from iOS Microphone in swift

Tags: ios, swift, microphone, decibel

TL;DR, How do I get raw voltage values from iOS microphone in swift

I am using AudioRecorder in swift 4 to take audio samples,cusing the `averagePower(channel: Int)` method, but I need a way to filter the decibel output from said function to dB(a) rather than dB, and to do that I need to be able to access the raw voltage value from the microphone. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.